# Why does summary(a$alpha) return class "-none-" when class(a$alpha) returns "numeric"?

Tags: r, class

I define list **a** & ask for the class of the first element **alpha**:

```
a <- list(alpha=c(1,2,3), beta=c("cat","dog","duck"), gamma=factor("a","b","a"))
class(a$alpha)
```

> [1] "numeric"

I then ask for a summary of **a**, which reports class *-none-* for **alpha**:

```
summary(a)
```

> ```
>       Length Class  Mode     
> alpha 3      -none- numeric  
> beta  3      -none- character
> gamma 1      factor numeric
> ```

Questions: (1) why is this? (2) I am a novice to R and to programming. What references would you recommend for the beginner who really wants to understand how R works (besides the [R language definition](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/manual/R-lang.html))? I find it hard to  understand things like the difference between mode, class, & type. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't claim to fully understand the *why* here, but as best I can tell, this is what's going on.

`summary.default` actually calls `oldClass` rather than `class`. *Why* I'm not sure, although I'm sure there's a good reason.

Somewhat cryptically in `?class` we find the following passages:

> Many R objects have a class attribute, a character vector giving the
>   names of the classes from which the object inherits. **If the object
>   does not have a class attribute, it has an implicit class, "matrix",
>   "array" or the result of mode(x) (except that integer vectors have
>   implicit class "integer").** (Functions oldClass and oldClass<- get and
>   set the attribute, which can also be done directly.)

So what's going on here is that `class` returns the *implicit* class (numeric). Note that `attr(a$alpha,"class")` returns `NULL`. Since the attribute doesn't exists, `oldClass` faithfully returns `NULL`.

As for the differences between mode, type and class, the first two are related, the third is sort of a separate idea. Mode and type are (I think) actually fairly well explained in the documentation. `mode` tells you the storage mode of an object, but it is relying on the result of `typeof`, so they are (mostly) the same. Or connected, at least. But the different values that `typeof` returns are simply collapsed down to a smaller subset.

Comment: I think I get it: since `a$alpha` has no `class` attribute, an implicit attribute `numeric`, given by `mode(a$alpha)`, is returned. But `a$alpha` is an integer vector, and, according to your bold text, should have implicit class `integer`. What am I missing?

Comment: @user7661 Don't make assumptions based on how things are printed at the console. Create your object `a` again, but instead use the vector `c(1L,2L,3L)` and try everything again.